# DNS Penetration Test and DNS Cache Poisoning

Tags: dns

I'm learning about the Dan Kaminsky attack on a server created to test out the attack. How would I go about using [dnspentest](http://dnspentest.sourceforge.net/)? Source code is available by clicking the link above the picture.

The readme says

```
java ServerKernelMain [Server IP] [IP of fake response]
```

(But I have to run this with sudo at the beginning)

For `<ServerIP>` I put the IP of the DNS server and as IP of fake response I put the IP address which I want the domain to be linked to after the poisoning. However, I'm confused how this works since it doesn't ask for the domain which will be poisoned.

Lastly, I'm not sure which port to use. I know I need to send to port X. In the code should it remain port 53 or should I change it to be port X?

Also when I start the program it just says

```
wait for request on **X**/UDP port...
```

Which is the main issue.

I have tried both, that's why I'm unsure which port to use or even if I'm doing anything correctly.

---

Alternatively, I did try [this](https://github.com/henryw14/DNS-Cache-Poisoning-with-Scapy) code however this is somewhat worse since it's not commented nor does it have variables for the Ip addresses so it's not explained or re-usable